# SignalR - Dont proceess notifications from current caller in javascript

Tags: javascript, signalr

I know this is really simple but I cant find the docs for this anywhere.

What i want to do is detect when an update has been sent by the current client so that the event is not reproduced locally.

I want to be able to get the client ID and the caller ID inside a signalR event to ignore ones where they match.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var drag = $.connection.drag;

        drag.move = function ( x, y,clientId) {
            if(clientId!== drag.clientId) //<-IE something like this (but this doesnt work)
                $("#box").offset({ top: y, left: x });
        };

        $("#box").draggable({
            drag: function (event, ui) {
                drag.sendMove(ui.position.left, ui.position.y);
            }
        });

        $.connection.hub.start();
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The connection id is `$.connection.hub.id`.

You can use that to block calls to yourself on the client side. This feature isn't enable on the server side as yet.